# C# single UDP listener with multiple senders giving data problems

Tags: c#, .net, udp

I have a program (windows service) that recieves data from UDP from multiple senders (~20 at the moment). Each sender "bursts" about 30 lines of CSV data every 10 seconds. In total around 12.000.000 lines are sent each day.

All incoming data are stored in text-files, one per day. Each file is ~1 GB in size. But sometimes we have daily files of only ~180 MB. It is very consistent - either one or the other, never somewhere in between. **So some days we loose ~80% of the incoming data.**

I have already verified, that the senders always sends approximately the same amount of data. So it lies somewhere in our receiver.

The UDP receiver is basically built like this:

```
using (UdpClient client = new UdpClient(listenPort))
{
    client.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 8388608;

    while (!cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
            var result = await client.ReceiveAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            var textData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result.Buffer);
            await dataHandler.Handle(textData);
    }
}
```

**dataHandler** is a class that appends all the lines into the textfiles

```
public async Task Handle(string data)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(Path.Combine(this.outputPath, GetFilename())))
    {
        await writer.WriteLineAsync(data);
    }
}

private string GetFilename()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".csv";
}
```

Before I investigate anything else: Is there anything in the above code, that could cause the problems that I am seeing? Either the UDP listener or the file-writing?

**Edit:** The data-loss is evenly spaced out during the day, so I wonder if it is something about the file-writing? Since a new file is created at midnight. Is it efficiently enough to instantiate a new StreamWriter for each line?

Comment: It would be useful to know what part of the data you are missing.  If I were to *guess*, I'd say that the stream is closing prematurely.

Comment: Are you opening and closing the client after each message or is the client always opened?

Comment: Wanna hear a UDP joke? You might not get it but I don't really care.

Comment: It seems like if you want guaranteed delivery, you'd use TCP.

Comment: I would send up a control streams. One as close to the reciever as possible so on machine, then on a computer on LAN then one on WAN. Track those very closely. See which one looses 80% data on the day it happens. I can bet you there is a switch problem or some stupid QoS that kicks in.... UDP... If there is such consitensy then it is something automatic that is causing it. Some kind of software, some kind of schedule.. keep digging.

Comment: @jdweng The client is kept open as long as the program is running.

Comment: @Carsten Gehling : Are you SURE!!!

Comment: @ppumkin I have segmented the received data for each sender. And by doing this, I can see, that the data-loss is evenly distributed on each sender. This is why I suspect that the error is in my receiving end.

Comment: @jdweng Well... not a 100% :-) I'll try to add some logging and see if I get any exceptions there.

Comment: Object of a "using" are dispose and that is one reason to use "using".  The stream dispose also flush and close streams.

Comment: @jdweng I was a bit premature before. I am, in fact, 100% sure that the UDP receive socket is not closed. Because if it did, the while-loop would exit with an exception, and the program would stop. This does not happen.

Comment: It depends on how fast it gets closed.  The closure is not instantaneously and any thing can happen.

Comment: That's why UDP packets use a checksum to indicate if the data came in successfully or it has to be resent again, UDP is known to have packetloss unlike TCP

Comment: On UDP you need to use a counter for every packet and if the counter on the next packet is higher then the current counter in your receive program then you missed a packet and have to resend it again. I found a good component you may use https://github.com/RevenantX/LiteNetLib

Comment: @jdweng is there any way that I can verify, that the socket is still open after each receive?

Comment: Open cmd.exe and type >Netstat -a  Also use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  When a connection closes you will see FIN.

Comment: @jdweng I was more thinking, verify from within my code. So that I might recycle the connection to get it going once more.

Comment: Before you make any assumption why the code isn't working find the root cause of the issue.  You are saying you need to recycle before you event know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I was looking at the wrong end of the problem. Data comes in on an UDP socket, data is written in files.

The observation about, that restarting the program solved the data-loss, was incorrect. And Also not done by me - you can't trust anyone.... :-)

The program is running in a VMWare virtual machine, and the storage is a SAN. I found out that the problem lay in the files being written. Some of the files are placed in a faulty location inside the SAN. If I rename or delete the file, so that a new is automatically created, all data are saved, and there is no data-loss.

A big thank you to everyone who pitched in with ideas to the UDP part.